How to refer to specific paragraph with the custom reference name?
Consider the following structure:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\section{Section}
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX\label{wp1}

See~\ref{wp1}.

\end{document}

The reference refers me to the given paragraph, but it will display the name corresponding to the section number. I would like to have a similar link but with my own choice of its name, say "paragraphXX". Could you please tell me how to reach this?

If you cross-post the same question on multiple sites, you should include links to all other versions of the question in every post, even in the original one. X-posting without explicit links has the risk of wasting both the time of users who might put time and effort into answering a post, which already has an answer elsewhere, as well as the time of users who might have the same problem but can't find the solutions you might have gotten on one of the other sites you x-posted your question

x-post https://stackoverflow.com/q/78874918/2777074

Labels can only refer to numbered content: here the only numbered thing is the section.

@JosephWright: what about hyperlinks? I did not manage to generate the proper solution with them, but at least they do not use the number.

If you look in the aux file, you will see that \newlabel has several arguments.  One is \@currentlabel which is (usually) a number.  One is the hyperref anchor name. (\@currentHlabel ?).  These macros are set by the last (local) call to \refstepcounter.

\paragraph will assign a number to a given paragraph is you set the secnumdepth counter to 4.

It's hard to tell what you actually want to do, because one hundred X's doesn't make a paragraph.

You can jump to anywhere in the document by setting a \phantomsection (which marks the location), followed by a regular \label{<label>}. Then, reference to that location (as a hyperlink) is achieved via \hyperref[<label>]{<stuff>}:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\section{Section}
\lipsum[1]

\phantomsection\label{wp1}
\lipsum[2]

See~\hyperref[wp1]{this paragraph}.

\end{document}


Clicking on this paragraph will jump you to Nam dui ligula....

Thanks! It works perfectly.
